# Why is there "volatility" within this options generator?

Tags: options

At this webpage https://optioncreator.com/ one can choose volatility. I dont understand what that is suppose to mean, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Volatility affects option pricing. The more volatility there is, the more chances that an OTM option will be ITM at expiration and vice versa, whereas if there is almost no volatility then it is less likely that there will be such a change.

When looking at option chains, you will see what is called an implied volatility. That means the volatility is calculated from the market price of the option, rather than the reverse.

Answer (score 0):

A European option pricing formula requires five variables to determine the theoretical price of an option:

- Strike price, underlying price, volatility, days until expiration, risk free rate

The market is an auction and buying pressure can make an option more costly (higher price than the theoretical value) and selling pressure can make an option less costly.  Via iteration, the option pricing formula can be used in reverse to calculate the implied volatility of the option or the volatility that is needed to achieve the current price.  IOW, when IV rises, so does option price and vice versa.

Comment: aaah right, forgot that price was not given!